# syslog set tag from api?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I can pump messages into [rsyslog](/questions/tagged/rsyslog) with a [syslogtag](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html) using the following from the command line using the `-t` option:

```
myprogram | logger -t MYTAG
```

And later filter based on that tag:

```
:syslogtag, contains, "MYTAG" /var/log/mylog
```

In the above example I am pumping stdout to the `logger` utility. However, I would like to push messages with that tag directly from `myprogram` to syslog but I can't seem to find anything related to adding tags [in the syslog documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html).

Using the following call:

```
#include <syslog.h>
...
syslog(LOG_DAEMON | LOG_DEBUG, "mymessage");
```

The syslogtag simply ends up being:

```
syslog
```

Comment: `logger` calls it a tag but the library [calls it ident](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/openlog.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple misunderstanding - before calling the `syslog` function I have to use the `openlog` function:

```
openlog("MYTAG", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON);
```

That does it!